# how to update multiple state at once using react hook react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I would like to know if I can use setState hook multiple times in same function.
For example, like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function(props) {
const [color, setColor] = useState(0)
const [size, setSize]= useState(0)
const [weight, setWeight] = useState(0)

const onClickRandomButton = () => {
    setColor(Math.random() * 10)
    setSize(Math.random() * 10)
    setWeight(Math.random() * 10)
}

return <div>
  <button onClick = {onClickRandomButton}>random</button>
</div>

}
```

I have tested, but it doesn't work as expected.
To set multiple values at once using hook, how should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Where is the `useState` part?

Comment: sorry, it was typo

Comment: This code should work as expected, what issues are you having?

Comment: is `conClickRandomButton` name also a typo?

Comment: yes, it's not the point what I am going to ask. it's just typo.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you're expecting this to do. This code will update all the states.

Comment: Code works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hill-1ypn7 ?

Comment: This should work. Try displaying the values  somewhere in the div to check them.

Comment: but sometimes it doesn't update all state.

Comment: Remember that setting state in React is asynchronous. If you try to operate on the new value in that same event handling function there is no guarantee that the state will have finished updating.

Comment: there is no enough detail in your question what do you mean "*sometimes it doesn't update all state*" be more descriptive and precise.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use one useState with object value for updating the styles at once:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function (props) {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({ color: 0, size: 0, weight: 0 });

  const onClickRandomButton = () => {
    setStyle({
      color: Math.random() * 10,
      size: Math.random() * 10,
      weight: Math.random() * 10,
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClickRandomButton}>random</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And if in any method you want to update just one property, for example: color, you could do something like this:

```js
...
  const handleEditColor = color => {
    setStyle({
      ...style,
      color
    });
  };

  // or

  const handleEditColor = color => {
    setStyle(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      color,
    }));
  };
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe `unstable_batchUpdates` will works for hooks as well as it works for class-based components. Besides prefix `unstable_` it's mentioned by [Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1091977127514292224) and [in React-Redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/batch) so I consider it's safe to use it:

```
import { unstable_batchUpdates } from 'react-dom';
...

const onClickRandomButton = () => unstable_batchUpdates(() => {
    setColor(Math.random() * 10)
    setSize(Math.random() * 10)
    setWeight(Math.random() * 10)
})
```

Comment: thanks, helpful to know this is available